# Query not returning in pg-promise the same result as pgadmin

Tags: json, postgresql, vue.js, pg-promise

I'm trying to do this request:

```
SELECT report.date_concerned,  
       json_object_agg('title', json_build_object('title', report.title, 'duration', report.duration, 'fk_category_id', report.fk_category_id, 'fk_client_id', report.fk_client_id, 'category_name', category.name, 'client_name', client.name)) AS details 
FROM report, 
     category, 
     client 
WHERE report.fk_user_id=2 
  AND report.fk_category_id = category.id 
  AND report.fk_client_id = client.id
```

GROUP BY report.date_concerned
ORDER BY report.date_concerned

When I'm doing it in pgadmin I receive this json:

```
    [
  {
    "date_concerned": "2021-08-01T22:00:00.000Z",
    "details": {
      "title": "élément 2 du 2 août",
      "duration": "02:15:00",
      "fk_category_id": 1,
      "fk_client_id": 2,
      "category_name": "Trotinettes",
      "client_name": "James Bond"
    },
    {
      "title": "élément 1 du 2 aout",
      "duration": null,
      "fk_category_id": 1,
      "fk_client_id": 2,
      "category_name": "Trotinettes",
      "client_name": "James Bond"
    },
    {
      "date_concerned": "2021-08-11T22:00:00.000Z",
      "details": {
        "title": "premier mot, deuxième mot, troisième mot, quatrième mot",
        "duration": "03:15:00",
        "fk_category_id": 1,
        "fk_client_id": 2,
        "category_name": "Trotinettes",
        "client_name": "James Bond"
      }
    }
  ]
```

But when I do it in pg-promise I receive it this way :

```
[
  {
    "date_concerned": "2021-08-01T22:00:00.000Z",
    "details": {
      "title": {
        "title": "élément 2 du 2 août",
        "duration": "02:15:00",
        "fk_category_id": 1,
        "fk_client_id": 2,
        "category_name": "Trotinettes",
        "client_name": "James Bond"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "date_concerned": "2021-08-11T22:00:00.000Z",
    "details": {
      "title": {
        "title": "premier mot, deuxième mot, troisième mot, quatrième mot",
        "duration": "03:15:00",
        "fk_category_id": 1,
        "fk_client_id": 2,
        "category_name": "Trotinettes",
        "client_name": "James Bond"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

As you can see the second entry of the same date is not returned.

I call pg-promise this way :

```
sendQuery("SELECT report.date_concerned,  json_object_agg('title', json_build_object('title', report.title, 'duration', report.duration, 'fk_category_id', report.fk_category_id, 'fk_client_id', report.fk_client_id, 'category_name', category.name, 'client_name', client.name)) AS details FROM report, category, client WHERE report.fk_user_id=$1 AND report.fk_category_id = category.id AND report.fk_client_id = client.id GROUP BY report.date_concerned ORDER BY report.date_concerned", urlValue,  callback);
```

sendQuery is this method :

```
function sendQuery(req, value, next) {
    db.any(req, value)
        .then(function (data) {
            next({
                    status: 'success',
                    data: data,
                    message: "it works",
            });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Error : ');
            console.log(err);
            next({
                status: 'error',
                data: null,
                message: 'an error occured'
            });
        });
}
```

The solution I'm looking for can be advices on pg-promise or on my pg query.

Comment: You are showing some invalid JSON here, with `"title"` listed twice on the same level, which would never happen.

Comment: @vitaly-t it's updated sorry about that

Comment: Best guess is you are not connected to the same data source in each case. Confirm your connection parameters.

Comment: unluckily it's connected to the same host, same database, same user and same port...

Comment: What do you get if you run the query in `psql`?  Add as update to question.

Comment: Most likely the same issue with column names as [here](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/issues/775).